# Erlang-like threads alternative or erl_nif performance

Tags: c++, c, erlang

I like a lot the thread architecture of Erlang (small cheap threads and the "share nothing" arhitecture), but it seems that Erlang is not perfectly suited for my application (these things would be more performant in C/C++, while Erlang is not best at that).

Well, as I already said, I REALLY like the thread architecture of Erlang (which isn't using OS threads). So, my question is - is there any similar library which implements this architecture for usage in C/C++ code? As far as I've googles, couldn't find anything better than "green threads" of Java (deprecated a long time ago and removed from current versions) and "fibers" of D (limited to one "real" thread, while Erlang threads are executed by Erlang on the most suitable "real" thread), which are somewhat similar, but not as powerful as Erlang threads.

If there is no such library, I am considering using the [erl_nif](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erl_nif.html) interface for writing the needed chunks of code in C/C++. But I couldn't find anywhere any performance analysis - is erl_nif is fast, or the overhead of "transforming" the Erlang terms/datatypes into C/C++ types is really big?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Akka](http://akka.io/) offers Erlang style actors but for Java/Scala, not C/C++.

From what I've read (e.g. http://www.scribd.com/doc/87376094/Erlang-and-OTP-in-Action#outer_page_324), NIFs are fast but potentially dangerous in that they can crash your whole Erlang program. You could try using Erlang ports (http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/ports.html) to communicate with C/C++, which is safer as the port keeps the non-Erlang code separate from the Erlang supervision tree.

Comment: Well, the integration should be really close, so ports are not an option for me. Thanks for the link, will check that.

Comment: Akka seems to be more and more interesting for now. Java instead of Erlang is an option for me. Does Akka provides cheap threads AND preemptive switching?

Comment: Akka indeed provides cheap threads, but i don't think it has preemptive scheduling.

Answer (score 2):

What you are after is called "Actor model"

There are quite a few C++ libraries that implement it

1. libcppa
2. Actor-CPP
3. Theron

Which one is better depends entirely on your particular use case.

However be aware, that in contrast to erlang's processes, **none** of them can do both cheap threads and preemptive task switching. You either map your actors to worker OS threads 1-to-1 and have preemptive switching, or use event based actors and cooperative multitasking.

Comment: Well, this is the main problem here - what I want is cheap threads AND preemptive task switching. Anyway thanks, that sounds interesting.

Comment: @Evengard, I don't think this is possible in c++ at all... Erlang makes it possible thanks to the virtual machine which runs the code and can suspend/resume the 'cheap threads' when it wants to.

Comment: erl_nif seems to be able to "delegate" that to C/C++ code, no? Imagining a thread manager entierly in Erlang and the actual logic in C/C++.

Answer (score 1):

`erl_nif` *does* use OS threads:

> Avoid doing lengthy work in NIF calls as that may degrade the responsiveness of the VM. NIFs are called directly by the same scheduler thread that executed the calling Erlang code. The calling scheduler will thus be blocked from doing any other work until the NIF returns.

So it does seem like Akka could be the best option for you.

Comment: You could use NIFs to interface OS threads. In that way the NIF needn't hang and you can get the benefit of using OS threads if that is what your application needs. Another way is to use *ports* as an interface to OS threads. NIFs behave like functions while ports behave like Erlang processes, from the Erlang side.

Comment: @rvirding The author of the question specifically does not want to use OS threads or ports.

Comment: Yes, but it is a way around blocking erlang threads while you wait for your C/C++ code to complete. You could run those in a "suitable" C/C++ thread package from Erlang without blocking and use Erlang for the parts it is best suited for.

Comment: This is a good point - about NIF calls blocking the underlying OS thread. Thanks. Anyway I already choosed Akka

Comment: @Evengard You're loss, IMAO :-)